# why must I earn separate reputation on all stack sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation

How many stack exchange sites are there and why is reputation not universal. It sucks having to earn reputation for every separate site. it is really annoying actually. It makes zero logical sense honestly.  Can anyone give a good logical explanation of this?

Comment: Why should expertise in graphic design automatically suggest you can moderate physics questions?

Comment: Note that not all reputation is separate -- the association bonus is reputation you can earn on all other sites due to actions on one.

Comment: Why should I gain reputation on a stack about "Webmasters" and "Web Applications" and then have to earn more rep to use "software Engineering" then have to earn more rep to use "Database Administrators" and who are you to say that I can't have expertise in both???? Limit yourself not me. People like me spend most of their life learning about multiple subjects not just one.

Comment: It would be like going to school, getting a good grade in one subject, and saying you should automatically get credit for every other subject.  Even when subjects are similar or related, each has it's own content that you need to demonstrate that you've mastered.  Otherwise school would consist of one course and you're done.

Comment: Higher reputation means higher privileges and responsibility. It doesn't make sense to give me the ability to close and delete questions in  https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/ just because I have that privilege in SO. Besides, If you have 200+ rep in any of the network sites, you get 100 reps by default when you join another community. That should be enough to vote, comment, flag and chat.

Answer (score 7):

To me each site has its own rules. Being good at one doesn’t mean being good at another or all sites.

Comment: And exactly how many sites are there? Then lets multiply that by the amount of time it takes to earn enough reputation on each site to be able to use it in order to complete the math problem and get the total value this adds = 0

Comment: As a developer working on a complex system with a reputation system, this setup makes no sense. Like I can't know how to program and rebuild an engine or rewire a car or answer a question on some other thing I know. Stack really believes each human knows only 1 subject?

Comment: @AkashicSeer You don't need any additional reputation (after the initial 1 point) to use the site, so what's the point in gaining reputation on _each_ site?

Answer (score 3):

There are [173](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) sites in total at the time of answering,  plus [area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) (a place for proposing and creating sites).

The principle of differential discrimination of ideas into separate categories for study to understand the nature of knowledge acquisition is called epistemology from the ancient Greek ἐπιστήμη (epistēmē) meaning knowledge.

Stack exchange is supposed to become a repository of knowledge, solutions and methodologies of finding solutions to problems in fields as disparate as cookery, biblical hermeneutics and computer programming (in various flavours). **Each site represents *millions of hours* worth of research, experience and hard study by it's members - a quick google search is no substitute for this responsive resource.**

Each culture's depth and variety of expression is a mark of the increase in a division and sub-division of knowledge, that is expressed here on the network, where one person cannot be an expert in all fields, as in life where a person cannot be all things to all people.

You wouldn't after all want to ask a question about how to approach a particular tricky social situation and have your question swamped by equally pressing questions about dimensional compactification or how to stop your souffle sinking.

Comment: Where did I say that? @AkashicSeer. How can you get in 10,000 hours practice as a surgeon at the same time as 10,000 hours learning Karate, and 10,000 Tiger-crane technique, and 10,000 hours learning Mandarin, and 10,000 hours learning medieval french literature .... School give one only a shallow view of the depth of knowledge and expertise that one might accomplish, but one must specialise to become expert in anything.

Comment: @AkashicSeer obviously you can know all those things, and understand the particulars of the separate communities, but you have to prove it.